# How do I pass two model objects to a get_queryset view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So what I'm trying to do is pass another model object (Question) to my view.The view currently returns a `get_queryset` of another model (Post). So this is the context I want to pass through so I can render it in my `polls.html`:

```
question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=1)
context = {'question': question})
```

**urls.py**

```
BV = BoxesView.as_view()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BV, name='news')
]
```

**view.py**

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    template_name = 'polls.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all().filter(category=1).order_by('-date')
        return queryset_list
```

**polls.html**

```
{% extends 'parent.html' %}

{% block polls %}

<p>question goes here</p> #this shows up
{{ question.question_text }} #this doesn't show up


{% endblock %}
```

**parent.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

        {% for post in post_list %}

            {% block polls %}

            {% endblock %}

        {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=70)

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

Comment: as i understand i have to do like this on your view `from myapp.models import Questions`. So you just need to import from another app your model

Comment: Ok so I just did that:
        from .models import Question, question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=1) -  Now how do I pass it through as context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `get_context_data()` method:

```
class BoxesView(ListView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=1)
        context['question'] = question
        return context
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) you can find similar example and other useful stuff.

Comment: Thankyou very much, this works. Do you mind explaining this line of code and how it's working? I'm not too familiar with super() so i'd like some clarification: context = super(BoxesView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

Comment: There you can find some cool answers: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it into your view. `from myapp.models import Questions`. Then you can use it, for example:

```
question = Questions.objects.get(pk=1)
```

If you have the same name of the model you can import like this:
`from myapp.models import Questions as Question1`

Comment: Ok so I've done that now, but that's just making the variable. How do I pass it through as context? Right now it's doing nothing.